# git much slower when connected to VPN using SSH

Tags: ssh, vpn, git

I noticed the other day that interacting with gitlab.com is extremely slow when I'm connected to the VPN at my job. If I disconnect, it's very fast. Here's an example I just did of a `git fetch` first with VPN disconnected, and then again with it connected. That was the only difference, and was moments apart.

```
➜ git:(autodeploy-test) time git fetch
git fetch  0.02s user 0.02s system 5% cpu 0.863 total
➜ git:(autodeploy-test) time git fetch
git fetch  0.02s user 0.03s system 0% cpu 1:16.46 total
```

You can see it takes 0.8 seconds without VPN, and with it, takes 76 seconds. These timings are consistent with what I've experienced. I'm hitting gitlab.com, and I'm using SSH. I'm not even sure what to troubleshoot at this point though, or what info might be useful. I just did an internet speed test on speedtest.net and got a download rate of 234 Mbps. This is a recent development; I don't recall anything like this happening until yesterday, and I've had this laptop for a few weeks now, and have been working with gitlab.com and on the VPN consistently.

Not sure where to look from here, any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I'm using Cisco AnyConnect client on a mac (OS is 10.15.3). The VPN servers I'm trying to connect to are both located at my office, about 5 miles away from my location. I haven't tried a different client.

Comment: It might be because of a particular VPN server... if possible, try a different server location.

Comment: I've only got two options for server and have tried both - no difference between those.

Comment: Where are the server locations for that VPN? Which VPN is it? Have you tried a different VPN? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cloned a different repo using HTTPS instead of SSH, and found that even when using the VPN performance was fine.

So I focused on looking up SSH+VPN specifically and I found someone [describing essentially the same behavior with bitbucket](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Slow-SSH-clone-pull-push/qaq-p/953843) - it was related to the fact that SSH was trying to use ipv6. If I forced git to use ipv4 (`git fetch -4`) then it performed just fine.

I configured SSH to use ipv4 globally and have had acceptable performance since. I also confirmed with IT that our VPN doesn't support ipv6, so this seems like the solution I'm going with. Thanks to everyone for their guidance/feedback!